# Bug when use attribute mask of v-text-field in vuetifyjs?

Tags: vuetify.js

**Hi, I am having a problem with attribute ' mask ' of v-text-field in vuetifyjs**,


For example to mask = "#####-######-#####", style = "text", everything is fine until **I used the Backspace, it just remove a few characters, then the cursor jump about first place** , it is offensive to me and the people who use the product. 
 How can I solve this problem
 

 
   it's same this video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/usmbwz6xhxjlfuy/2017-12-15_02-35-27.mp4?dl=0

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12 md3>
        <v-text-field 
          id="example"
          name="example" 
          v-model.trim="form.example"
          mask="#####-######-#####"
          type="text"
          label="Backspace"
          class="ma-3"
        >
        </v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      example: ''
    }
  })
})
```

https://codepen.io/hsgsneiger/pen/LBbdJw


Thanks!

Comment: See [ask]. Questions should be stand-alone, so [edit] your question and put the [mcve] in the text of the question. No one is going to follow that link, which will almost certainly be dead in weeks.

Comment: Can you please give a clearer example? I try typing and hitting backspace in your CodePen example and nothing out-of-the-ordinary happens

Comment: Interesting, I did see the cursor position jump randomly when typing quickly. Backspace seemed to have no issue, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only happens when typing slow 
And it's a bug and I think it has not been fixed yet

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2797

Answer (score 0):

Example: Use mask: phone

```html
<v-text-field
    label="Mobile Number"
    mask="phone"
 ></v-text-field>
```